# Extract all words from text and remove specific unwanted words

Tags: php, filtering, preg-replace, text-extraction

I want to replace in this string:

```
This is my Store, it has an amazing design; its creator says it was losing money and he doesn't want to maintain it
```

All non-alphanumeric characters except for `'`(doesn't) and all chosen conjunctions:

```
is, it, its, the, this, if, so, and
```

So far I've managed to obtain this result:

```
Array
(
    [1] => This
    [2] => my
    [3] => Store
    [4] => has
    [5] => an
    [6] => amazing
    [7] => design
    [8] => s
    [9] => creator
    [10] => says
    [11] => was
    [12] => losing
    [13] => money
    [14] => and
    [15] => he
    [16] => doesn
    [17] => t
    [18] => want
    [19] => maintain
)
```

Here is the code:

```
$string = "This is my Store, it has an amazing design; its creator says it was losing money and he doesn't want to maintain it";
$words = array_filter(preg_split('/\s+/', preg_replace('/\W|\b(it|the|its|is|to)|\b/i', ' ', $string)));

print_r($words);
```

https://3v4l.org/cLrM4

But as you can see it is replacing `it` when it should replace `its` and it is also replacing `'` in `doesn't`.

Can somebody help me understand where I'm doing something wrong?

P.S: Also I need it to be **case-insensitive** that `/i` works pretty farcically

Comment: I would use explode instead of preg_split. Explode is not as heavy function and it's  equally capable to split a string on space.

Comment: Oh, even better, i hadn't even thought about it :D Thank you! I've replaced it with explode <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your regular expression to this:

```
/\W\B|\b(it|the|its|is|to)\b/i
```

The pipe in `|\b` did not make sense to me, maybe it was a typo. The additional `\B` after `\W` will make sure that a non-alphabetical character is only replaced when it is not immediately followed by an alphabetical character. This is less restrictive than what you asked, but could be useful for other cases as well, like words having hyphens (e.g. mother-in-law).

Answer (score 1):

First, remove all whole words which you mentioned in your blacklist (technically these are not conjunctions in the English language) in a case-insensitive `preg_replace()` call.

Then use `str_word_count()` to extract whole words (even contractions and hyphenated words).

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/4uAGd))

```
print_r(
    str_word_count(
        preg_replace('/\b(?:its|i[stf]|the|this|so|and)|\b/i', '', $string),
        1  // mode 1 returns words as a flat, indexed array
    )
);
```

Alternatively, you can isolate all words in the string with `str_word_count()` first, then filter with a case-insensitive `udiff()` comparison.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Qp352))

```
print_r(
    array_values(
        array_udiff(
            str_word_count($string, 1),
            ['its', 'is', 'it', 'if', 'the', 'this', 'so', 'and'],
            'strcasecmp'
        )
    )
);
```

Output (from either script):

```
Array
(
    [0] => my
    [1] => Store
    [2] => has
    [3] => an
    [4] => amazing
    [5] => design
    [6] => creator
    [7] => says
    [8] => was
    [9] => losing
    [10] => money
    [11] => he
    [12] => doesn't
    [13] => want
    [14] => to
    [15] => maintain
)
```